# Trying to get an Android jabber app to check for a string in new messages and return a toast message

Tags: android, xmpp, toast, ejabberd, instant-messaging

I have been able to create the if statement that checks for the string and it returns the toast message that i created but it keeps showing the toast message every time i open the chat. even if the most recent message doesn't contain the string I am looking for so i am assume it isn't checking to see if it is the last message received and it doesn't check to see if it is unread. the code is below. the reason i am trying to do this is because my parents share a facebook account and i want an easy way to display if the message is signed mom or dad. the code below only has the check for mom once it works i will be adding the check for dad signature. I am using the open source message client Xabber. Thank you for help.

```
  public void setVisibleChat(String account, String user) {
    final boolean remove = !AccountManager.getInstance()
            .getArchiveMode(account).saveLocally();
    AbstractChat chat = getChat(account, user);
    if (chat == null)
        chat = createChat(account, user);
    else {
        // Mark messages as read and them delete from db if necessary.
        final ArrayList<MessageItem> messageItems = new ArrayList<MessageItem>();
        for (MessageItem messageItem : chat.getMessages()) {
                if (!messageItem.isRead()) {
                messageItem.markAsRead();
                messageItems.add(messageItem);
            }

            if (chat.getLastText().contains("Mom") && (!messageItem.isRead()));{
                Toast.makeText(Application.getInstance(), "Message from Mom!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
        Application.getInstance().runInBackground(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Collection<Long> ids = getMessageIds(messageItems, remove);
                if (remove)
                    MessageTable.getInstance().removeMessages(ids);
                else
                    MessageTable.getInstance().markAsRead(ids);
            }
        });
    }
    visibleChat = chat;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I am also trying to get the same Read status of MessageItem in android xabber. but messageItem.isRead() always returning true even when receiver didn't opened the message. can you suggest me if you have any idea about this issue

Comment: @Raj you should probably post your code so people in this community have a better understanding of what could possibly be going wrong. I stopped working in this project a while ago after my parents got smart phones and they setup individual FB accounts so i didnt have the need anymore. I believe I had it working almost perfectly at the time but dont have the code anymore. Post the code and I will do my best to help you.

Comment: Hi, I have updated the exact issue with code snippets as a separate Question. Below is the url.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29776948/issue-with-android-xabbar-message-read-status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got an extra semi-colon here

```
if (chat.getLastText().contains("Mom") && (!messageItem.isRead())); <------
```

So your next block of code containing the Toast show statement will always be executed.

Remove the semi-colon

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response. unfortunatly now the toast doesnt come up at all i am guessing i need to change what the if statement is checking. if (chat.getLastText() must not be the right.

Comment: No problem. You can run the app in debug mode, and set a breakpoint in the code. This will allow you to step through and pinpoint the cause of your problem. If my answer has helped you, please at least upvote it. If it helped you solve the problem, please accept it. Thanks

Comment: this did work partially it is still not checking to see if the message is unread. But it is better then it was. i cant up vote i don't have enough rep. again thank you so much. just have to work on the && statement.

Comment: Hi, I am also trying to get the same Read status of MessageItem in android xabber. but messageItem.isRead() always returning true even when receiver didn't opened the message. can you suggest me if you have any idea about this issue